# Javafx Extends ToggleButton

Tags: java, javafx, toggle, togglebutton

I create a custom toggleButton that extends from ToggleButton.

The problem is that it doesnt respect the ToggleGroup given to.
I can select more than one.
But if you set the default class `ToogleButton`, it only allow me to select one at a time.

```
private void createAvatarButton(Avatar avatar) {
    MPButton button = new MPButton(avatar.getPath());
    button.setToggleGroup(avatarGroup);
    button.setUserData(avatar);
    button.setPrefHeight(100);
    button.setPrefWidth(200);
    button.textProperty().bind(I18N.getString(TAG.getKey(avatar.getName())));

    tilePane.getChildren().add(button);
}

public class MPButton extends ToggleButton {

    /**************************************************************************
     * 
     * Private fields
     * 
     **************************************************************************/

    private String image;


    /**************************************************************************
     * 
     * Constructors
     * 
     **************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Creates a new CheckComboBox instance with an empty list of choices.
     */
    private MPButton() {
    }

    public MPButton(String image) {
        initialize(image);
    }

    private void initialize(String image) {
        this.image = image;
        getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
        setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.TOGGLE_BUTTON);
        // alignment is styleable through css. Calling setAlignment
        // makes it look to css like the user set the value and css will not
        // override. Initializing alignment by calling set on the
        // CssMetaData ensures that css will be able to override the value.
        ((StyleableProperty<Pos>)(WritableValue<Pos>)alignmentProperty()).applyStyle(null, Pos.CENTER);
        setMnemonicParsing(true);     // enable mnemonic auto-parsing by default
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                         *
     * Stylesheet Handling                                                     *
     *                                                                         *
     **************************************************************************/

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MPButtonSkin(this, image);
    }




    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                         *
     * Stylesheet Handling                                                     *
     *                                                                         *
     **************************************************************************/

    private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "toggle-button";

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
        return MPButton.class.getResource("/styles/component/c-mpbutton.css").toExternalForm();
    }


}


public class MPButtonSkin extends BehaviorSkinBase<ToggleButton, BehaviorBase<ToggleButton>>{

    // visuals
    private final ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private final StackPane stackPane;
    private Blend blush;
    private Glow selectGlow;
    private ColorAdjust disabledAdjust, monochromeAdjust;
    private ImageView iconImageView;
    private Pane pane;

    private static final String SYMBOL = "/img/main/symbol.png";


    public MPButtonSkin(ToggleButton control, String image) {
        super(control, new BehaviorBase<>(control, Collections.<KeyBinding> emptyList()));

        toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton.setText(control.getText());
        toggleButton.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");

        stackPane = new StackPane();

        toggleButton.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 4, 20));

        pane = new Pane();
        ResponsiveUtil.bindImageUrlCover(pane, getClass().getResource(image).toExternalForm());


        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        Image iconImage = new Image(getClass().getResource(SYMBOL).toExternalForm());
        iconImageView = new ImageView();
        iconImageView.setFitHeight(15);
        iconImageView.setFitWidth(15);
        hbox.getChildren().add(iconImageView);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 6, 0));

        // Color Adjust
        disabledAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        disabledAdjust.setBrightness(-0.7);
        selectGlow = new Glow(2.7f);
        monochromeAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        monochromeAdjust.setSaturation(-1.0);
        monochromeAdjust.setBrightness(0.5);

        blush = new Blend(BlendMode.MULTIPLY, monochromeAdjust,
                new ColorInput(0, 0, pane.getWidth(), pane.getHeight(), Color.GOLD));


        toggleButton.selectedProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
            if (nv) {
                blush.setTopInput(new ColorInput(0, 0, pane.getWidth(), pane.getHeight(), Color.GOLD));
                pane.setEffect(blush);
            } else {
                pane.setEffect(selectGlow);
            }
        });

        toggleButton.disabledProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean nv) -> {
            if (nv) {
                pane.setEffect(disabledAdjust);
                iconImageView.setImage(iconImage);
            } else {
                pane.setEffect(null);
                iconImageView.setImage(null);
            }
        });

        addWidthProperty(control);
        addHeightProperty(control);

        toggleButton.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        stackPane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        pane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);


        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(pane, hbox, toggleButton);
        stackPane.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        getChildren().add(stackPane);
    }

    private void addWidthProperty(ToggleButton control) {
        pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(control.prefWidthProperty());
        stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(control.prefWidthProperty());
    }

    private void addHeightProperty(ToggleButton control) {
        pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(control.prefHeightProperty());
        stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(control.prefWidthProperty());
    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * 
     * Overriding public API
     * 
     * @return double
     **************************************************************************/

    @Override protected double computeMinWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return stackPane.minWidth(height);
    }

    @Override protected double computeMinHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return stackPane.minHeight(width);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return stackPane.prefWidth(height);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return stackPane.prefHeight(width);
    }

    @Override protected double computeMaxWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return getSkinnable().prefWidth(height);
    }

    @Override protected double computeMaxHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return getSkinnable().prefHeight(width);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about MPButtonSkin? Does it have anything to do with your problem? I compiled and run your code without overriding createDefaultSkin() (since you didn't attach it) and it worked as expected.

Comment: @M.S. Thanks for the reply, I just attached the Skin, I couldnt find a problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises in MPButtonSkin's constructor. You create a new `ToggleButton` every time:

```java
public MPButtonSkin(ToggleButton control, String image) {
    super(control, new BehaviorBase<>(control, Collections.<KeyBinding> emptyList()));

    toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
    toggleButton.setText(control.getText());
    toggleButton.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");

    // ...
}
```

The problem is that the new `ToggleButton` doesn't refer to the same `ToggleGroup` (set to null by default). You can add it manually after constructing the new `ToggleButton`:

```java
// ...
toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
toggleButton.setToggleGroup(control.getToggleGroup()); // add this line
// ...
```